# Simulating a website in an application

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I tried simulating the report button at 9GAG as a start by doing:

```
string url = "http://9gag.com/gag/aKBQ00O";
string parameters = "radio-report=1";
using( WebClient wc = new WebClient( ) ) {
    wc.Headers[ HttpRequestHeader.ContentType ] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString( url, parameters );
    Console.WriteLine( HtmlResult );
}
```

and a `WebException` occurred with a message that the server sent `404 NOT FOUND` error.
For those who doesn't want to go to 9GAG to see the form I am simulating, here:

```
<section id="modal-report" class="badge-overlay-report modal report">
    <header>
        <h3>Report Post</h3>
        <p>What do you report this post for?</p>
        <a class="btn-close badge-overlay-close" href="#">✖</a>
    </header>
    <form id="form-modal-report" class="popup-report" action="" onsubmit="return true;">
        <div class="field checkbox">
            <label><input name="radio-report" type="radio" value="1"> Contains a trademark or copyright violation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field checkbox">
            <label><input name="radio-report" type="radio" value="2"> Spam, blatant advertising, or solicitation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field checkbox">
            <label><input name="radio-report" type="radio" value="3"> Contains offensive materials/nudity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field checkbox">
            <label><input name="radio-report" type="radio" value="4"> Repost of another post on 9GAG</label>

            <input id="jsid-repost-link" type="text" class="text" placeholder="http://9gag.com/gag/post_ID">
        </div>

        <div class="btn-container">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-text-loading="Please wait ...">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

It is taken of course from http://9gag.com/gag/aKBQ00O.

Am I missing something? or I am at the completely different direction of doing this?

Comment: If you right click on the Report button with your browser, you'll see that just below it in the markup is an anchor tag with a URL that points at "http://9gag.com/read/delete?id=aKBQ00O". It appears that making an HTTP get request to that URL is enough to accomplish what you're seeking.

Comment: @mason It's when you want to delete your post. (It's hidden because it's not your post)

Comment: I did not check the actual Url it is requesting. Deleted my answer

Comment: Checking the source code, the form has no "method" attribute. It will send the data using the query string. After seeing @mason s comment, I deleted my answer.

Comment: There is javascript going on and the final method is POST and the final Url /report-post  and the data to be sent look like entryId=aKBQ00O&type=4

Comment: @OguzOzgul But when you kill on his link you will see that an error has occurred. (You will need to remove the `"` at the end, s\he did a mistake)

Comment: I updated my answer and undeleted it. I got the same response { okay:false} from the server. It requires authentication by the way. You still will not be able to achieve what you want probably, but at least can know the correct values to post

Comment: @OguzOzgul I got the false okay too with `/read/report?id=XXXXXX`, how did you found the report-post thingy? I will try searching for the authenctication.

Comment: That's why I +1 @mason s comment. Use developer tools of your browser, enable network trace, click the link and you will see.

Comment: I had to say, it is returning the same {okay:false} when I click the REPORT link and select radio button 4 on the dialog window and submit.

Comment: May be it is expecting the link to the duplicate post when you select the 4th radio button, which I did not enter into the textbox. So specifying link parameter to the duplicate link may change that response to [ okay: true }

Comment: Updated my answer the last time, good night.

Answer (score 1):

Checking by developer tools network tab

I can see that it actually posts to

```
http://9gag.com/report-post
```

And the data is like the following: (type = 4 for the fourth radio button)

```
entryId=aKBQ00O&type=4&link=
```

So you should change your code like this: (But type and link parameters should be defined dynamically)

```
string url = "http://9gag.com/report-post";
string parameters = "entryId=aKBQ00O&type=4&link=";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(url,  parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(HtmlResult);
}
```